# Expandable list view Indicator does not set on right side

Tags: android

I want to set my indicator icon that comes on left by default, should appear on right side.
I had tried all the techniques i find on google but it seems like some thing is wrong with my expandablelistview or there is some other way around to do it, 
I tried :
explistobj.setInicatorBounds(...)                       not works:( 
adding attribute in xml
android:indicatorLeft="250dp"
android:indicatorRight="300dp"                          not works:(

code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ExpandableListView expListView;
        List<String> listDataHeader;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // get the listview
            expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

            // preparing list data
            prepareListData();
            setDimens();

            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview Group click listener
            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Listview Group expanded listener
            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Listview Group collasped listener
            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

            // Listview on child click listener
            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        /*
         * Preparing the list data
         */
        private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("mylist0");
            listDataHeader.add("mylist1");
            listDataHeader.add("mylist2");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
            mylist0.add("item1");
            mylist0.add("item2");
            mylist0.add("item3");

            List<String> mylist1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                mylist1.add("Item1");
            mylist1.add("Item2");
            mylist1.add("Item3");
            mylist1.add("Item4");
            mylist1.add("Item5");
            mylist1.add("Item6");

            List<String> mylist2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            mylist2.add("item1");


            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), mylist0); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), mylist1);
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), mylist2);
        }
        public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
        {
                // Get the screen's density scale
                final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
                return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
        } 

        public void setDimens()
        {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
            int height = size.y;
            Display display2 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int width2 = display2.getWidth();  // deprecated
            int height2 = display2.getHeight();  // deprecated
            //expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width2-GetDipsFromPixel(35), width2-GetDipsFromPixel(5)); //not works
            expListView.setIndicatorBounds(expListView.getRight()- 40, expListView.getWidth()); //not works

        }
    }

xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                <!-- 
                android:indicatorLeft="250dp"
                android:indicatorRight="300dp"                          
                 -->
             />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please try this, it was work in my scenario.
this is xml coding of expandable listview
**layout.xml**

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#d4d4d4"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

**group_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" android:state_empty="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right"></item>
```

then code in java file.
**expandableExample.jav**

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int width = metrics.widthPixels; 
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
        searchExpListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    } else {
        expandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
        searchExpListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
    }

public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {
    // Get the screen's density scale 
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

it's complete code for right indicator in expandable listview.

Now there is fine library available for same. If you want to use recyclerview and want to use custom view for such thing, Use groupie library that also explain expandable example. [groupie](https://github.com/Genius/groupie). this library is require android data binding. Handle multiple view in recyclerview and also having expandable feature.

Comment: i know, if you are working in horizontal and portrate mode both, then please put this code in onConfigurechnage() also.
else change orientation it will give you issues.