# Default icon indicator of expandable list view not shown at right side in lollipop version

Tags: android, icons, expandablelistview, indicator

Am developing an app with expandable listView. i made the default expand/collapse icon indicator at right side by using the following code,

```
explvList.setIndicatorBounds(width-GetDipsFromPixel(35), width-GetDipsFromPixel(5)); 
Here width means device width. 

Convert pixel to dip  
public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
{ 
    // Get the screen's density scale 
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale 
    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

and i got the design correctly in jellybean version as shown bellow,
[image]

But when i moving to lollipop version, indicator is show at left as normally like this,[image]

how can i solve this?any suggestion please?

Comment: have a look here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878813/expandable-list-view-indicator-does-not-set-on-right-side

Comment: yes. now it work correctly.